# In what ways can a game of XCOM:EU end?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've just seen a 'win' ending, which I suspect may be *the* ending, but thought I'd check what endings the game has just in case.

Obviously you can lose by having eight or more countries leave the council, but are there any other ways to lose?

And does the game have more than the one 'win' ending?

Comment: There is win or lose. I never heard of anything else or saw anything else and I lost 3x times now, in different ways, but it was the same cutscene.

Comment: Is there a different way to lose except for having too many countries defect? Well, there is another lose condition in the final mission, but when I triggered it I just got a popup allowing me to reload and no cutscene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only two possible outcomes to the game, winning, by killing the "priests" at the temple ship, or losing, where 8 nations have left the XCOM project.

There is another condition, where the volunteer (the soldier used in the gallop chamber) must survive the final battle (temple ship). However, if they die during the mission, you will be prompted to reload the game and no cut scene is shown. This happens also when playing in Iron-man mode.

Those are all the endings available.

Comment: I had my team wiped out and my volunteer psi soldier killed at the end of the last battle playing Iron man.  It gave me the option to reload and when I pressed reload, it went to a file cut scene and gave me the victory?!?! What a funny bug.  Unfortunately now I have to start over but the game says I won when i really just got annihilated.

Comment: @Quinma, did you get the achievements related?

Comment: Yes I did. And I saw the end video and victory stats screens.

Comment: This happened to me (volunteer killed on temple ship mission) on my Ironman play as well - I got the option to restart the mission, and it restarted the mission as one would expect.

Answer (score -3):

Volunteer has to survive for cut scene canon. Game end is all the same, only one victory condition.