# When do you lose the game?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I've played `Xcom: Enemy unknown` for 21 hours (according to steam) and suddenly, at October 1st (internal game date) I see a "defeat" movie of alien taking mind control of the council president.

Why did this happen? Does this game has a time time limit and I lost because I did not progress with main game missions (I stopped at alien ship assult)? I did not lose to many of the council members (I think). Can you explain this?

Comment: `I did not lose to many of the council members (I think)` That's not very accurate... According to [In what ways can a game of XCOM:EU end?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89316/in-what-ways-can-a-game-of-xcomeu-end), you can only lose when 8 or more countries leave the XCOM project.

Comment: @Nolonar I've just checked, you are right! I've lost 8 countries. If you post this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: We can just close this as a duplicate of the question @Nolonar linked to.

Comment: @FEichinger as you find appropriate.